# Staircase Issue

Tags: wood, stairs

There is a wooden staircase going from the kitchen to the basement in our house. A small gap has opened up between one of the steppers (the part of the stair case you step on)
and the stringer. In addition, there is a small amount of squeaking when you use it.

From a cosmetic point of view, I think it is fine. I looked at the bottom (e.g. underneath it) and it all looks fine. However, I am worried about a safety issue. Should I be?

[image: A picture]

Here is another picture:

[image: A closeup of the gap]

Comment: Only unsafe if someone(teens) sneaking up or down and know about it and skip the step.  No pictures so will suggest adding a couple of screws to tighten it.  Good if unfinished, not good look if finished.  Reminds me I have a 40 year step I need to fix.

Comment: @crip659 I added a picture.

Comment: Carpet should hide screws.  Stain or paint don't hide screws as well, without more work.

Comment: @crip659 Cosmetics is not an issue. Safety is the issue. If there is no safety issue, we are going to leave it alone. I am starting to believe there is no safety issue.

Comment: @crip659 Where would you put the screws? Would it be from the stringer to the stepper?

Comment: Stepper to stringer uses shorter screws(~2 1/2 to 3 inch).

Comment: @crip659 To add those screws seems to me to require taking off the stepper. Sounds like a big job and not something I would be anywhere qualified to do. Since your original comment said that there was no unreal safety issue, I am most likely going to leave it alone. I am hoping that you or somebody else will post an answer.

Comment: Stringers are under the ends of the stepper/tread.  Drill pilot holes and screw down. No removal needed.

Comment: @crip659 May last comment said:  that there was no unreal safety issue, I am most likely going to leave it alone. I should have said:  that there was no real safety issue, I am most likely going to leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern way to install stairs is to do a rough stair case first with stringer and treads / risers.  The next thing is to put your skirt board against the wall.  The stair stringers are not visible from the top.  The finished treads/risers are then install on top of the structural treads/risers and horizontally against the skirt board.

It is hard to see in your picture but possibly these are rough stairs with green carpeting installed ( though the tread bullnose makes me think otherwise )

As far as safety, assuming the stairs were built with proper fasteners, even a 1/4" gap is not going to constitute a safety issue.  I can't tell from the image how wide the gap between the tread and the skirt board is.

Comment: The gap is about 3/16 of an inch. The house (and the staircase) was built in 1962.

Answer (score 0):

Around Oct 5, I noticed that the problem was getting worse. One of the risers had a gap in it. Therefore, I decided it was not safe. We brought in a carpenter and he agreed that it needed work. We hired the carpenter and he fixed the problem.